# Generic method to get content values for any table in database?

Tags: android, sqlite

So I understand you store data in content values so you can later write to a database:

```
private static ContentValues getContentValues(Game game) {
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(tableName.Cols.UUID, game.getId().toString());
   values.put(tableName.Cols.TITLE, game.getTitle());
   etc.

   return values;
}
```

However I was hoping to create a method that would take a table name as a parameter and I would be able to execute the above code using the provided table name.

Is it possible to create generic method for getting content values?

Comment: Probably not possible without an ORM library.

Comment: How should that code know which method belongs to which column?